# How do I regaing focus on form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, focus

I have a PC in a corporate production environment and need to make sure the same program loads over and over. I upgraded to Windows 7 and my start-up program keeps losing focus because of MacAfee. I tried to uninstall MacAfee but it's an enterprise version and it won't let me. I tried to do some programming in my vb.net application to regain focus but nothing has worked.

Here's a picture of how the program boots up - notice the form is a lighter color and has lost focus:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYrqQ.jpg

Here's a picture of how the form SHOULD load up after I click on it with the mouse to fix it - notice the darker color of the form:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnNQ6.jpg

Here's why I think MacAfee is the problem - if I alt tab, the MacAfee updater icon shows up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAbZ9.jpg

Any ideas to solve my problem programmatically or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's sample code on a timer that gets the foreground window handle, if it's not Me, make it Me

```
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As IntPtr
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Long

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim focusedWindow As System.IntPtr
    focusedWindow = GetForegroundWindow()
    If Not Me.Handle.Equals(focusedWindow) Then
        SetForegroundWindow(Me.Handle)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can probably eliminate the Timer and use the Form.Deactivate event.

Answer (score 0):

In form1.shown sub write this:

```
For i = 0 To 100
    Me.Activate()
Next
```

This will try 100 times to focus on your form when it shows up.